# Solve logarithmic equation :$\log( \sqrt{4-x} ) - \log( \sqrt{x+3} ) = \log(x)$

Tags: polynomials, logarithms, factoring

I'm getting stuck trying to solve this logarithmic equation:

$$
 \log( \sqrt{4-x} ) - \log( \sqrt{x+3} ) = \log(x)
$$
I understand that the first and second terms can be combined & the logarithms share the same base so one-to-one properties apply and I get to:
$$
 x = \frac{\sqrt{4-x}}{ \sqrt{x+3} }
$$
Now if I square both sides to remove the radicals:
$$
 x^2 = \frac{4-x}{x+3}
$$
Then:
$$
 x^2(x+3) = 4-x
$$
$$
 x^3 +3x^2 + x - 4 = 0
$$

Is this correct so far? How do I solve for x from here?

Comment: There are [formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) for solving cubic equations, but there does not seem to be any "nice" solution in this case.

Comment: Yes, very good! Can you check the exercise again? Wasn't there a $2$ or $\sqrt x$ somewhere? Wolfram Alpha says, has one real solution but ugly:
$x=0.893289..$

Comment: @Berci Thanks, I copied it correctly. It looks like they are looking for the ugly solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fine so far.  I would just use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%5E3%2b3x%5E2%2bx-4=0), which shows there is a root about $0.89329$.  The exact value is a real mess.  I tried the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), which failed.  If I didn't have Alpha, I would go for a numeric solution.  You can see there is a solution in $(0,1)$ because the left side is $-4$ at $0$ and $+1$ at $1.$

Comment: Okay, I put the equation in Wolfram Alpha and got the same root, thank you. Do you have a link that explains how to get a numeric solution?

Comment: @JustinBrown:  There are many methods, discussed in numerical analysis texts.  The simplest to explain is bisection.  We know that $f(0) \lt 0$ and $f(1) \gt 0$, so there is a root in there.  Check $f(0.5)=-2.625$ and we know the root is in $(0.5,1)$, then check $f(0.75)$ and so on.  Keep going until the interval is small enough.  There are other methods that converge faster.

Comment: I'm familiar with that technique I just didn't realize that is what you meant. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is correct so far.

There is clearly a root between $0$ and $1$.  Either use numerical methods to find it is about $0.893289$ or (not recommended) [solve the cubic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) to get $$\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{211}{108}}}  + \sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{211}{108}}} -1$$